# Replace all hyphens at the end of line by '?'

Tags: bash, perl, sed

I have following file:

```
------FGJFG----HULKJ----LKHJ-------
---JKLJLK-----UIOUOPPOIPIPIPOPIP---
GGJKHKLJK----------JKLHKLJLKJLKJLKJ
```

and I want this:

```
??????FGJFG----HULKJ----LKHJ???????
???JKLJLK-----UIOUOPPOIPIPIPOPIP???
GGJKHKLJK----------JKLHKLJLKJLKJLKJ
```

i.e., I want to replace all leading and tailing '`-`' by the same number of '`?`', but not the '`-`' between letters

I know how to do this for leading:

```
sed -i ':a;s/^\(-*\)-/\1?/;ta' file
```

but how can I modify the command to replace '`-`' at the end of lines?

Comment: did you wanna a perl solution?

Comment: Thanks, Perl will be also fine, but it should be quick, I need to modify several thousands of such files, each with several hundreds of lines...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\G-|-(?=-*$)/?/g'
```

**Output:**

```
cat file

??????FGJFG----HULKJ----LKHJ???????
???JKLJLK-----UIOUOPPOIPIPIPOPIP???
GGJKHKLJK----------JKLHKLJLKJLKJLKJ
```

Comment: You did forget the leading spaces.

Comment: Thanks @Jotne: I overlooked it initially, it is added now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -F"[^-]" '{a=b="";for (i=1;i<=length($1);i++) a="?"a;sub(/^-+/,a);for (i=1;i<=length($NF);i++) b="?"b;sub(/-+$/,b)}1' file
??????FGJFG----HULKJ----LKHJ???????
???JKLJLK-----UIOUOPPOIPIPIPOPIP???
GGJKHKLJK----------JKLHKLJLKJLKJLKJ
```

Answer (score 0):

Through Perl.

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=[^-])-+(?=[^-\n])(*SKIP)(*F)|-/?/g' file
??????FGJFG----HULKJ----LKHJ???????

???JKLJLK-----UIOUOPPOIPIPIPOPIP???

GGJKHKLJK----------JKLHKLJLKJLKJLKJ
```

`(?<=[^-])-+(?=[^-\n])` matches all the hyphens which are at the middle.  `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the match to fail and `-` after `|` will match all the hyphens from the remaining string.

Comment: Why you people attacking me only? What's wrong with the above regex? I love to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl,

```
perl -pe 's/^(-+)/"?" x length($1)/e; s/(-+)$/"?" x length($1)/e' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The same looping mechanism that you're using for the leading dashes can be used for the trailing ones, with appropriate minor changes:

```
sed -i -e ':a;s/^\(-*\)-/\1?/;ta' \
       -e ':b;s/-\(-*\)$/?\1/;tb' file
```

Note that this assumes GNU `sed` on several grounds; you have to do things a bit differently with the BSD (Mac OS X) version of `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

This one-line Perl program will do as you ask

```
perl -pe 's/(?|^(\-+)|(\-+)$)/$1=~tr|-|?|r/eg' myfile.txt
```